# CSS and jQuery: .name vs name^= (i.e. classes vs "id arrays")

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Consider the following three scenarios:

(1):

```
<div class="zones"></div>
<div class="zones"></div>
<div class="zones"></div>
```

vs (2):

```
<div id="zone1"></div>
<div id="zone2"></div>
<div id="zone3"></div>
```

vs (3):

```
<div id="zone1" class="zones"></div>
<div id="zone2" class="zones"></div>
<div id="zone3" class="zones"></div>
```

Given that you can target every `<div>` by using accordingly either the `.zones` or `div[id^=zone]` selectors (both in CSS and jQuery),

Is there any advantage of using (1) or (3) over (2)?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of an ID is to uniquely identify an element. If you don't need to identify each element individually, there is no reason to give each one of them an ID. Likewise, if you don't need to associate the three elements with one another, there is no reason to assign them a common class name.

If you're going to go with option 3 because you need both IDs and classes, that's when you consider the difference between selectors.

In CSS, `.zones` is [less specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) than `div[id^=zone]` because of the missing type selector (a class selector and an attribute selector are equally specific by themselves). Of course, if you want to balance the specificity of both selectors, you can consider `div.zones` instead of `.zones`.

Class selectors are also usually optimized so they're far more straightforward to match, both in CSS and jQuery. The resultant difference in performance is not significant, but if you can match the exact same elements by class, there is no reason not to use a class selector over an attribute selector. Thus, again, if you're going to style or manipulate the three elements as a group, assign them a class name and select by that class.

Comment: Even if you don't need to identify each element individually, but only need to target all of them as a group, Why would you prefer the class over the "indexed id"? You can still match all of the elements with the attribute selector, and you get an advantage: if in the future you need to target one element individually, you already have them uniquely identified, so you don't need to change your HTML! There's no advantage of using the class!

Comment: `id^=zone` does not only target `zones`. Also, I think, it should be slower than class selector.

Comment: @Racso: You never said anything about changing existing HTML. All you're doing is presenting three options and asking what the advantages of each are. I'm saying if you don't need those IDs, don't use IDs. If you just want to refer to them as a group, use a class.

Comment: @Racso: If you're trying to minify your HTML for whatever reason, you can go even further with the `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` selector and not have to use *either* ID or class attributes. But as that is outside the scope of your question I shan't elaborate.

Comment: @BoltClock The advantages/disadvantages are seen if the given options are put into some context. We shall suppose that they are part of some real-life code, that may even change in the future (e.g. If someone asks "What disadvantage does using inline styling have?", a valid answer would be that "you would have to modify your existing markup if you want to change the style").
About the nth-child selectors: please elaborate; I don't think that's out of scope. I think, however, that it's not the same: by using "indexed ids" you can move the elements in your code without breaking the selectors).

Comment: @Jashwant has a point: if another element has an id="zonedHeader", it will be undesirably selected, too.

Comment: @Racso: I see where you're coming from now, but if I were to consider different possible scenarios the answer would become far too broad, and I was trying to keep the answer reasonably scoped. As for `:nth-child()`, you have a point there about reordering the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the situation.Personally I wouldnt care about saving those nanoseconds and would like to write a cleaner html that every developer understands (more class based because id can be used more while javascripting)

You can obviously write your entire html with class,tags,[child + siblings selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/),[nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child).

just an example:

```
.mainclass > .innerclass > a{
cloro:red;
}
```

the same thing could be done if you assign `id=something to a tag`:

```
#something{
color:red;
}
```

use class:only when multiple dom elements share the same characteristic.

use Id's:only when different dom elements share unique characterictic.

But ultimately.it all comes down to writing cleaner,simpler and understandable codes.

Comment: no..and i get your point completely,but what i am saying is as the code increases..managing it becomes slightly difficult..lets say if somebody styles an element with id rather than classes..this would surely do the job but i as a developer always use id for javascript purpose and i believe design has to handeled on classes.This is the best thing to do.Simple and avoids lot of confusion.And either way..both of them are quite easy to understnad